# Amplify Triger destination does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm new to AWS ecosystem and launched a Amplify few weeks ago which running smoothly. Now I did some cleanup on the console and maybe I deleted such trigger/logs/etc... that result to not detecting the new code commit and not triggering the code build on every commit.

Error after push commit: 1 trigger failed to run. This does not affect your push. AmplifyTrigger-d2nqnmfpnrqgq2: The destination does not exist.

Tried creating a web hook but I still need to manually call the webhook which is not ideal.